# How to add an equation column while maintaining current grouping

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am having some issues where adding a final column causes my groupin to not function properly (so I think)

I have this code:

```
with deliveryData AS(
SELECT NetworkID, Creative_Type, SUM(Impressions) AS Impressions, SUM(clicks) AS Clicks,
CASE WHEN Creative_Type = "Display" 
  THEN 
    CASE WHEN Impressions >= 100000000 
      THEN rate.DisplayAdsL3_CPM 
    WHEN Impressions > 50000000 AND Impressions < 100000000
      THEN rate.DisplayAdsL2_CPM
    WHEN Impressions <= 50000000 
      THEN rate.DisplayAdsL1_CPM  
      END
WHEN Creative_Type = "Tracking"
  THEN
    CASE WHEN Impressions = 0
      THEN rate.ClickTracker_CPC
    ELSE
      rate.Tracking_CPM
    END
END AS AdServeRate
FROM Dashboard.CM_2020_03
LEFT JOIN Dashboard.campaignManager_ClientRateTable as rate ON NetworkID = rate.Partner_ID
Group By 1,2,5
)
SELECT *
FROM deliveryData as data
```

Which gives me a very clean result (3 rows total):

```
Row NetworkID   Creative_Type   Impressions Clicks  AdServeRate 
1   1234        Tracking        0           100     0.02
2   1234        Display         6775966     59151   0.15
3   1234        Tracking        520179      0       0.07
```

My intent is to ad a final column calculating (depending on the Creative_Type) Imperssions or clicks * AdServeRate.

I added another CASE statement to the above code:

```
with deliveryData AS(
SELECT NetworkID, Creative_Type, SUM(Impressions) AS Impressions, SUM(clicks) AS Clicks,
CASE WHEN Creative_Type = "Display" 
  THEN 
    CASE WHEN Impressions >= 100000000 
      THEN rate.DisplayAdsL3_CPM 
    WHEN Impressions > 50000000 AND Impressions < 100000000
      THEN rate.DisplayAdsL2_CPM
    WHEN Impressions <= 50000000 
      THEN rate.DisplayAdsL1_CPM  
      END
WHEN Creative_Type = "Tracking"
  THEN
    CASE WHEN Impressions = 0
      THEN rate.ClickTracker_CPC
    ELSE
      rate.Tracking_CPM
    END
END AS AdServeRate,
CASE WHEN Creative_Type = "Display" 
  THEN 
    CASE WHEN Impressions >= 100000000 
      THEN ROUND(rate.DisplayAdsL3_CPM * Impressions/1000,2)
    WHEN Impressions > 50000000 AND Impressions < 100000000
      THEN ROUND(rate.DisplayAdsL2_CPM * Impressions/1000,2)
    WHEN Impressions <= 50000000 
      THEN ROUND(rate.DisplayAdsL1_CPM * Impressions/1000,2)  
      END
WHEN Creative_Type = "Tracking"
  THEN
    CASE WHEN Impressions = 0
      THEN ROUND(rate.ClickTracker_CPC * Clicks,2)
    ELSE
      ROUND(rate.Tracking_CPM * Impressions/1000,2)
    END
END AS AdServeFee
FROM Dashboard.CM_2020_03
LEFT JOIN Dashboard.campaignManager_ClientRateTable as rate ON NetworkID = rate.Partner_ID
Group By 1,2,5,6
)
SELECT *
FROM deliveryData as data
```

However, instead of having 3 rows with the added Fee, I now have 207 rows.

I've also tried using the result of the first case (AdServeRate) in my second, but it tells me it doesn't recognize AdServeRate

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: Are you really sure that you need `LEFT JOIN` clause here, assuming that each row in Dashboard.CM_2020_03 table appears in the results of merging?

Comment: @mk_sta the joined table contains the rates I need.  It contains the appropriate rate per impression volume.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the separating the logic out into different CTEs can help.

```
with deliveryData as (
  select NetworkID, Creative_Type, sum(Impressions) as Impressions, sum(clicks) as Clicks
  FROM Dashboard.CM_2020_03
  group by 1,2
),
calc_ad_serve_rate as (
  select 
    *,
    CASE WHEN Creative_Type = "Display" THEN 
            CASE WHEN Impressions >= 100000000 THEN rate.DisplayAdsL3_CPM 
                 WHEN Impressions > 50000000 THEN rate.DisplayAdsL2_CPM
                 WHEN Impressions <= 50000000 THEN rate.DisplayAdsL1_CPM  
            END
         WHEN Creative_Type = "Tracking" THEN
            CASE WHEN Impressions = 0 THEN rate.ClickTracker_CPC
            ELSE rate.Tracking_CPM
         END
    END AS AdServeRate
  from deliveryData
  LEFT JOIN Dashboard.campaignManager_ClientRateTable as rate ON NetworkID = rate.Partner_ID
),
final as (
  select 
    *,
    case when Creative_Type = 'Display' then round(AdServeRate*Impressions/1000,2)
         when Creative_Type = 'Tracking' then round(AdServeRate*Clicks,2)
         else 0
    end as AdServeFee
  from calc_ad_serve_rate
)
select * from final
```

If you are open to unsolicited advice, I would consider breaking up your logic even more to avoid the complex case statments.

```
with deliveryData as (),
     cte_cpm as (),
     cte_cpc as (),
     unioned as (select * from cte_cpm union all select * from cte_cpc)
select * from unioned
```

Imagine accidentally charging a client the CPC rate for CPM campaigns or vice versa.  A hard-to-read, complex case statement makes that type of error much more likely.